# Using multiple spinner(android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-spinner

so im really new to the world of android and im trying to code some very basic stuff.I would like to know whats the code to display and make multiple spinner works; so far I did this but I get an error "The type new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.onNothingSelected(AdapterView)".Heres XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.spinnertest.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
    android:entries="@array/Type" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:entries="@array/Produits" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="93dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and heres java code:

```
package com.example.spinnerTest;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Spinner s1,s2;
TextView txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String val = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            txt.setText(val);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String val = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            txt.setText(val);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });}}
```

So im just trying to make 2 spinner(and more after) to display and works at the same time.I also gets these errors when launching it on emulated device:

```
10-12 15:39:19.388: E/Trace(831): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-12 15:39:20.269: D/AndroidRuntime(831): Shutting down VM
10-12 15:39:20.269: W/dalvikvm(831): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception         (group=0x40a13300)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.spinnertest/com.example.spinnertest.MainActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.example.spinnertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-12 15:39:20.279: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the @Override annotations above the methods of the anonymous classes.

Also you need you must implement both methods for interface to work.

```
s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String val = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        txt.setText(val);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});

s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String val = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        txt.setText(val);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I just tried that by adding @Override to both of them and I still get 2 error: Insert ; to complete statement after the second Override and Syntax error on token "}", delete this token after the } after the first Override; maybe you could fix the full code with Override and paste it here? thank you(by the way if I add ; or delete } it adds more errors)

Comment: there was also missing  }} after last line " });".Theres no error however when I try to run it on emulator it does crash; any idea why? By the way thank you you help me a lot :)

Comment: If it crashes, you must be getting an error message in the logcat. Update your question with it.

Comment: I added the errors in the question.I have no clue why it does crash(im not used to android)

Comment: @Johnny_b also post your current (updated) java code.

Comment: @Johnny_b yep as I thought `s2` is null. Add `s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);` after you initialize `s1`.

Comment: thanks,it worked, however I couldnt see even my spinner and neither my items in it I tried some stuff and it (finally) ended by working.thanks a lot @user3249477

Comment: @Johnny_b you're welcome. Glad you finally solved it :)

Comment: And is there a way to make integer field or spinner smaller in the graphical layout of eclipse? I mean each time I try to make them smaller it just go back to his original size when I release the click...it does that for spinner and text field element...